# umask settings in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: umask

For system-wide umask setting I edited "/etc/pam.d/common-session". `session optional pam_umask.so umask=027`
It doesn't have any effect. It does work on Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know why this won't work in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I also tried adding it to `/etc/pam.d/login`, per instructions on `man pam_umask`, and that didn't work either.